# AWSのEC2でmod_rewriteが使えないようです。

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, bitnami

WordPressで [SiteGuard WP Plugin](https://www.jp-secure.com/siteguard_wp_plugin/) を使いたいです。

AWSのEC2でmod_rewriteが使えないようで、ログインページを変更する機能が使えないです。

[AWSでmod_rewriteが効かない場合](https://yasigani-ni.com/php/aws%E3%81%A7mod_rewrite%E3%81%8C%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88/)

上記の記事を見つけたので、SSH接続で、記事に有ったコマンドを実行しました。

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

でも、ファイルが無いようで、新規にファイルが作られてしまいました。
`:q`と入力して保存せずに終わりましたので、ファイルはできていないです。

AWSのEC2にWordPressをインストールして使っています。

このhttpd.confというファイルは、別のところにあるのでしょうか？
すみません。教えてください。お願いします。

Comment: OSなどの環境情報、どのように構築が行われたか、などが開示されないことには第三者からはどこに問題があるか特定できないと思うのですが。

Comment: sayoriさん、ありがとうございます。
MacBookAirで、ターミナルでSSH接続しています。
AWSは、EC２のLinuxのOSで、WordPressをインストールしました。

Comment: 気になっているのは、Webサーバーに何を使っているのか書かれていないことです。Linuxには[多数のディストリビューション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)があり、それごとに設定ファイルの位置は異なるのが特徴ですので、説明になっていません。

Comment: すみません。
OSの内容再確認します。

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-125-generic x86_64)

  *** Welcome to the Bitnami WordPress 4.8.1-0 ***

Comment: SSH接続した画面で、情報確認できました。すみません。

Answer (score 2):

[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/4236)に陥っています。確認した事実と、それを元に推測した内容を明確にし、何を解決すべきかをよく考えてください。

> mod_rewriteが使えないようで

とのことですが、[Access An Application Using Only A Single Domain With Apache](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/)のドキュメントではmod_rewriteが使われているため、使えないという推測は誤っている可能性が高いです。また、[List Installed Apache Modules](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/check-installed-modules/)にてモジュール一覧の取得方法も説明されています。推測が正しいか確認してください。

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/apachectl -M
```

---

> ログインページを変更する機能が使えない

こちらが本来解決したい問題ではありませんか？

[2014-10-27 プラグイン WordPress HTTPS (SSL)をご利用の場合の注意事項](https://www.jp-secure.com/siteguard_wp_plugin/info/)によると

> プラグイン WordPress HTTPS (SSL) [wordpress-https]と、SiteGuard WP Pluginの「ログインページ変更」の機能を同時に使用することはできません。
>   WordPress HTTPS (SSL)以外にも、ログイン関連の設定を変更するプラグインは、SiteGuard WP Pluginと同時に使用できない可能性がありますので、ご注意ください。

と説明されています。該当する環境かを確認してはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
私は、冒頭で、”WordPressで SiteGuard WP Plugin を使いたいです。”と書いているので、問題を明確にしています。
私がネットで調べた限りでは、mod_rewriteが原因かのように思いましたので、mod_rewriteが使えないのかなという趣旨で質問を投稿しました。、

Comment: ログインページのURLを変更することができたら、良いです。
SiteGuard WP Pluginのプラグインが使えるように解決できることが、質問の趣旨です。

Comment: 教えていただきましたプラグインを使っていないか確認します。
SSLを使えるようにしたので、教えて頂いたプラグインが有効にしている可能性があります。

Comment: Really Simple SSLというプラグインを使っていました。
教えて頂きました内容で、解決策を探ります。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: お名前.comの共有サーバーで動いているWordPressのプラグインを確認したところ、同じ組み合わせで、SiteGuard WP Pluginのログインページ変更の機能を使うことができています。AWSに何か原因があると思います。

Answer (score 1):

sayuriさんのコメントにあるように環境の情報がないと確かなことは言えないのですが、下記を調べる方法の参考まで。

> このhttpd.confというファイルは、別のところにあるのでしょうか？

`httpd -V`を実行するとhttpdのビルド時のパラメータを取得できます。
そのなかの、`SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`がデフォルトの設定ファイル(httpd.conf)のパスです。
もし、`SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`が相対パスで記載されていた時は、`HTTPD_ROOT`からの相対パスのはずです。

※起動オプションで別の場所の設定ファイルを使うこともできるので、上記のパスに必ずあるわけでないですが、まず確認してみるのは一つの手だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
と表示されました。
早速、アクセスしましたが、新しいファイルとなってしまいました。
パスを変えて色々試しましたが、今のところまだ見つかっていません。

Comment: HTTPD_ROOTはどのように表示されたでしょうか？SERVER_CONFIG_FILEが相対パスなので、HTTPD_ROOT + SERVER_CONFIG_FILEがdefaultの設定ファイルの場所です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
このように、表示されます。
HTTPD_ROOT="/bitnami/lampstackDev-linux-x64/output/apache2"

Comment: ~/apps/wordpress/conf$ ls
banner.conf  htaccess.conf   httpd-prefix.conf  php-fpm
certs        httpd-app.conf  httpd-vhosts.conf
でした。

Comment: ~/apps/bitnami$ ls
banner

Comment: このディレクトリが無さそうです。lampstackDev-linux-x64/output/apache2

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/understand-config/ によると、bitnami のapach設定ファイルは/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf にあるようですが、確認してもらえますか？　（httpdの起動オプションで設定ファイルのパスヲ指定してそうですね。`ps -ef | grep -e httpd -e apache`してみると、実際の起動オプションがわかるかもしれません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。
パス見つかりました、。
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
で、ファイル開くことができました。
これから、修正作業します。

Answer (score 1):

みなさま、ありがとうございます。

sudo vi /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
で、下記のサイトの記事で修正するように書かれている部分の修正を行いました。
https://yasigani-ni.com/php/aws%E3%81%A7mod_rewrite%E3%81%8C%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88/

AWSは、.htaccessが無効と知りました。
https://qiita.com/hnagao/items/b7b35ad01a8ba8a42548

そのため、下記の記事を元に、
http://kzhishu.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/12/07/090000

sudo vi /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf
で修正しました。
RewriteRule ^login_xxxxx(.*)$ wp-login.php$1 [L]
の記載を追加しました。
login_xxxxxは、例です。

これでログインページの変更ができました。